# Access mariadb docker-compose container from host-machine

Tags: python, mysql, docker, mariadb, docker-network

I'm trying to access a mariadb-container from a python script on my host-machine (MacOS).
I tried all network_modes (host, bridge, default), but nothing works.
I was able to connect to the container through phpmyadmin, but only if both containers are in the same docker-compose-network.

Here is my `docker-compose.yml` with the attempt on network_mode host:

```yaml
version: '3.9'

services:
  mariadb:
    image: mariadb:10.9.1-rc
    container_name: mariadb 
    network_mode: bridge
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    volumes:
      - ...
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mysqlroot
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=mysqlpw
      - MYSQL_USER=test
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=test1
      - TZ=Europe/Berlin

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin:5.2.0
    network_mode: bridge
    container_name: pma
    # links:
    #   - mariadb
    environment:
      - PMA_HOST=mariadb
      - PMA_PORT=3306
      - TZ=Europe/Berlin
    ports:
      - 8081:80
```

Any tips on how I get access to the container through the python mariadb package?

Thanks!

Comment: just ran your docker compose and check the access to mariadb, everything okay. Could you add how you are trying to access the database in your python code? the problem is probably there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every thing seems okay, just check the params when trying to connect to the db:

- host: 0.0.0.0
- port: 3306 (as in the docker-compose)
- user: test (as in the docker-compose)
- password: mysqlpw (as in the docker-compose)
- database: test1 (as in the docker-compose)

example:
`db = MySQLdb.connect("0.0.0.0","test","mysqlpw","test1")`

Comment: turns out the problem was the mariadb package. I tried it with the mysql connector and it worked perfectly fine. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. Your answer helps me a lot. But I don't know why host is 0.0.0.0 and it works.

Comment: host 0.0.0.0 is the "same" thing as 127.0.0.1 or localhost, is your machine, the machine where the code is running